# Custom Button works in Salesforce Sandbox but does not in Salesforce Production

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I hope someone can help me figure this out.  I connected my Docusign to my salesforce sandbox, created, the templates, created the custom button etc.   With my custom button, I set the template, and message and it sends the document right away.  Everything was working in my salesforce sandbox but when I changed my connector to point to salesforce production, the button in production does not work.  I compared the code with sandbox and it is exactly the same.  In production, it still asks for the template even though I specified in my custom button what it is.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';
var RSL='';
var RSRO='';
var RROS='';
var CCRM='';
var CCTM='';
var CCNM='';
var CRCL=''; 
var CRL='';
var OCO='';
var DST='';
var LA='';
var CEM='';
var CES='';
var STB='';
var SSB='';
var SES='';
var SEM='';
var SRS='';
var SCS ='';
var RES=''; 

//*************************************************// 
// Modify individual options here: 

// DocuSign Template ID (default no template) 
DST = '9FD26FA6-1007-4134-85D5-0073BA8F2613'; 
SSB = '0';

//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+ "&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRC‌​L+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="‌​+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SC‌​S="+SCS+"&RES="+RES; 

//*******************************************//
```

Comment: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********//
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************//
// Modify individual options here:
// DocuSign Template ID (default no template)
DST = '9FD26FA6-1007-4134-85D5-0073BA8F2613';
SSB = '0';

Comment: //********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********//
window.location.href = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Lead.Id}&RC="+RC+

"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//

Comment: I have the exact same code in my sandbox and production sfdc environments but the button works in sandbox but not in production.

Comment: Please always include code in the question instead of in the comments -- it's more readable in the question, and can be formatted as code.  (I've moved the code from comments into question for you this time.)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190303/docusign-for-salesforce-crcl-not-populating.

Comment: Do you have the same version of the managed package in both production and sandbox?