# DocuSign for Salesforce Custom Button - Auto Populate Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I have a custom button in Salesforce that I am trying to configure to auto populate the recipients.  I have a custom Salesforce object 'Approver' that is related to the object I have the custom button configured for.  The approver object is a lookup relationship object to the Contacts object.  Approver object has the fields of 'Approver Email', 'First Name', 'Last Name', and 'Role'.  Approver Email, First Name, and Last Name fields are formula fields bringing this information from the contact . The Role field is a picklist field that contains the same values as I have configured in my envelope settings for DocuSign for Salesforce.

I have tried to write the code in the button JavaScript to auto populate the contacts selected in the Approver object, but the button is not even inserting recipient roles into the envelope.  Below is how I have coded the JavaScript of the sections of CCRM, CCTM, CCNM, and CRCL

Any help would be much appreciated

CCRM ='1~Appr 1 Level 1;2~Appr 2 Level 1;3~Appr 3 Level 1;4~Appr 4 Level 1;5~Appr 5 Level 1;6~Reviewer 1;7~Reviewer 2;8~Reviewer 3;9~Reviewer 4;10~Reviewer 5;11~Appr 1 Level 2;12~Appr 2 Level 2;13~Appr 3 Level 2;14~Appr 4 Level 2;15~Appr 1 Level 3;16~Appr 2 Level 3;17~Appr 3 Level 3;18~Appr 1 Level 4;19~Appr 2 Level 4;20~Appr 1 Level 5;21~Appr 2 Level 5';
// Custom Contact Type Map
CCTM ='1~Signer;2~Signer;3~Signer;4~Signer;5~Signer;6~Acknowledge Receipt;7~Acknowledge Receipt;8~Acknowledge Receipt;9~Acknowledge Receipt;10~Acknowledge Receipt;11~Signer;12~Signer;13~Signer;14~Signer;15~Signer;16~Signer;17~Signer;18~Signer;19~Signer;20~Signer;21~Signer';
// Custom Contact Note Map (default no note)
CCNM = ''; //Ex: 'Decision Maker~Note for DM;Economic Buyer~Note For EB;DEFAULT_NOTE~Default Note'
// Custom Related Contact List (default object contact)
CRCL ='Approver__r,Email~Approver_Email__c;FirstName~First_Name__c;LastName~Last_Name__c;ApRole~Role__c;LoadDefaultContacts~0'
//Ex:'Approver__r,Email~Email__c;FirstName~First_Name__c;LastName~Last_Name__c;Role~Role__c,LoadDefaultContacts~0'

Answer (score 3):

1. I sugest you break down your button code, remember this is jscript
   and you need to make it debuggable
2. Here is a reference for the documentation [Docusign Custom Button Documentation for Salesforce](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20for%20Salesforce%20Custom%20Button%20Logic.pdf)
   and here [DocuSign Custom Button Sample Documentation for Salesforce](https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-admin-guide/admin-guide/customize-envelope-contacts)
3. I suspect you want loadDefaultContacts~1 in CRCL per the documentation "The LoadDefaultContacts parameter determines if
   default contacts for the source object type are loaded (0 – do not 
   load, 1 – load)."
4. How I would debug:

   a. Add Alerts (controlled by debug var, change to true to see them)

   b. Add Try Catch finally

   c. Review the below Sample Custom button and compare to what you are trying to accomplish, taking it one step at a time

   d. use Chrome to debug and step into the virtual function that is created on your Salesforce page so you can see the variables and related values that are generated from the {!} SF tokens, etc

**-SAMPLE GENERIC CUSTOM BUTTON:-**

```
/*REQUIREMENTS:
   1. Set Email Subject to Opp Name
   2. Set CRL to User
   3. Set signer tyoe to Carbon Copy
   Created for Salesforce Version 5.2
   Source Version of this button 1.0
   Code Reviewed by: Group Accenture

*/

var location ='\\';
var debug = false;


try
{

    var CES = 'Please sign this document for {!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(Opportunity.Name))}';
    var CRL = 'Email~{!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(User.Email))};LastName~{!URLENCODE(JSENCODE(User.Name))};Role~CCSigner;RoutingOrder~1;'; 
    var CCTM = 'CCSigner~Carbon Copy';
    var CCRM = 'CCSigner~CCSigner';

    location = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.id}&CES="+CES+"&CRL="+CRL+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CCRM="+CCRM;


}
catch (e)
{

    alert("Error Occured"+e.message);

}
finally
{
    if(debug)
    {
        alert(location);
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = location;
    }
}
```

**-SAMPLE COMPLEX CUSTOM BUTTON USING SOQL AND BUILD UP OF CRL/CCRM/CCTM -**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/DocuSign_JavaScript")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

/*REQUIREMENTS:
   1. Set CRL based on Business logic using Product Type and User Roles
   2. Set DST based on Business logci using Product Type
   3. Business Logic (Expand Below here)
      ====See Section Business Rules====
   4. By default this is for sandbox, prod value must be true for it to be using values for Templates in Production mode
   5. This is not a one button click send
   Created for Salesforce Version 5.4
   Source Version of this button 0.5 (beta)
   Code Reviewed by: DocuSign (TBD)

    ====See Section Business Rules====
    DocuSign Button Logic

    1. IF Docusign_Checkbox__c = TRUE 
       AND Sector__c = ‘Life Sciences’
       THEN 
       Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
       Signer 2 = Life Sciences Sector Lead Role

    2. IF Docusign_Checkbox__c = TRUE
       AND Sector__c = ‘Financial Services’
       THEN 
       Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
       Signer 2 = Financial Services Sector Lead Role

    3. IF Docusign_Checkbox__c = TRUE
       AND Sector__c <> ‘Life Sciences’,‘Financial Services’
       THEN 
       Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
       Signer 2 = Health Plans & Providers Sector Lead Role

    4. IF Docusign_Checkbox__c = FALSE
       THEN 
       Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
       Signer 2 = Practice Lead with Signing Power

   Current Questions, Assumptions and clarifications outstanding
a. What client Sign's? 
         i. I see the internal signers, but who is going to sign from the "clients" perspective, or will the person using the button decide
    b. Can you send me the LS template, renamed to txt (xml or zip will not come through)
    c. I will need the production template ids (guids) as they are different from Prod to Demo
    e. What do you want the button to say aka "Send with DocuSign" or something else for your business process
    f. I assume if I am missing the below you want an error message with all the issue shown without allowing the user to send:
        i. No user for Role
        ii. Data for Lead if not DocuSign
    g. I assume the following as well:
        i. The new doc with the 4 scenarios superceds the original email with the different condition
        ii. You don't want to change the default on the below:
            I. Email Subject or Message will be the standard default for the Managed Package in the admin
            II. The expirations and reminders will be the standard default for the Managed Package in the Admin
            III. I will not load the default contacts or attachments
            IV. I will load the recipients based on the business rules only given in the new document
            V. I will load the template based on the business rules only given in the new document
            VI. This is NOT a one button click send

        DEMO
        EBM = DST = 1989696D-F058-42E5-9C5B-8718482E2C1A
        NVS = DST = A906436D-5352-40DE-A9F8-1EE0795E4266
        LS = DST = 4CFE35EC-C8A4-4090-9B72-024F1DE26757

4CFE35EC-C8A4-4090-9B72-024F1DE26757
        PROD
        LS DST
        6048B3CD-D2C5-44BE-9630-51CFCFBD092D

        EBM DST
        B3D6159B-5BE3-4B80-8e8e-96173120D0EF

        NVS DST
        855790D3-6121-496F-B870-D0B276A54611

*/

var location ='\\';
var debug = false;
var prod = false;

//Define Business Rule Functions below for:
// Getting User Role
function getUserInfoForRole(roleName,templateRole, routingOrder)
{
    var recipient = '';

    try
    {

        var result = sforce.connection.query("select id, Email, FirstName, Lastname from User where userroleid in (Select id from UserRole where Name ='"+roleName+"')");
        var userForRole = result.getArray("records");

        recipient = 'Email~'+userForRole[0].Email+';FirstName~'+userForRole[0].FirstName+';LastName~'+userForRole[0].LastName+';Role~'+templateRole+';RoutingOrder~'+routingOrder+';,';

    }
    catch(e)
    {
            if(debug)
            {
                alert(e.message);
            }
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return recipient;
}

try
{

    //Set DST based on Business Logic 
    var DST = '';

        //Set CRL based on Business Logic in Function (TBD)
    var CRL = ''; 

    //Set Signer Type to Signer for each Role as Signer (Looks to be just two in templates)
    var CCTM = '';

    //Set Signer Type to Signer for each Role (Looks to be just two in templates)
    var CCRM = '';


    if({!Contract.Docusign_Checkbox__c}==1)
    {

        if(debug)
        {
            alert('DocuSign Checked')
        }

        if('{!Contract.Sector__c}' == 'Life Sciences')
        {
            //Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
            CRL = getUserInfoForRole('Business Integrity Director', 'Business Integrity', '1');
            CCTM = 'Business Integrity~Signer;';
            CCRM = 'Business Integrity~Business Integrity;';

            //Signer 2 = Life Sciences Sector Lead Role
            CRL = CRL + getUserInfoForRole('Life Sciences Sector Lead', 'Client Signer', '2');
            CCTM = CCTM + 'Client Signer~Signer;';
            CCRM = CCRM + 'Client Signer~Client Signer;';

            if(debug)
            {
                alert('Life Sciences')
            }

            if(prod)
            {
                DST = '6048B3CD-D2C5-44BE-9630-51CFCFBD092D'
            }
            else
            {
                DST = '686DBA37-EBF3-410F-90E3-7E3F36A95694';
            }

            if(debug)
            {
                alert(DST)
            }

        }
        else if('{!Contract.Sector__c}' == 'Financial Services') 
        {
            //Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
            CRL = getUserInfoForRole('Business Integrity Director', 'Business Integrity', '1');
            CCTM = 'Business Integrity~Signer;';
            CCRM = 'Business Integrity~Business Integrity;';

            //Signer 2 = Financial Services Sector Lead Role
            CRL = CRL + getUserInfoForRole('Financial Services Sector Lead', 'Sector Lead', '2');
            CCTM = CCTM + 'Sector Lead~Signer;';
            CCRM = CCRM + 'Sector Lead~Sector Lead;';


            if(debug)
            {
                alert('Financial Services')
            }

            if(prod)
            {
                DST = 'B3D6159B-5BE3-4B80-8e8e-96173120D0EF'
            }
            else
            {
                DST = '1989696D-F058-42E5-9C5B-8718482E2C1A'
            }

            if(debug)
            {
                alert(DST)
            }           

        }
        else if(('{!Contract.Sector__c}' != 'Life Sciences') && ('{!Contract.Sector__c}' !='Financial Services'))
        {
            if(debug)
            {
                alert('Not Life Sciences or Financial Services')
            }
            //Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
            CRL = getUserInfoForRole('Business Integrity Director', 'Business Integrity', '1');
            CCTM = 'Business Integrity~Signer;';
            CCRM = 'Business Integrity~Business Integrity;';

            //Signer 2 = Health Plans & Providers Sector Lead Role
            CRL = CRL + getUserInfoForRole('Health Plans & Providers Sector Lead', 'Sector Lead', '2');
            CCTM = CCTM + 'Sector Lead~Signer;';
            CCRM = CCRM + 'Sector Lead~Sector Lead;';

            if(prod)
            {
                DST = '855790D3-6121-496F-B870-D0B276A54611'
            }
            else
            {
                DST = 'A906436D-5352-40DE-A9F8-1EE0795E4266'
            }

            if(debug)
            {
                alert(DST)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Error
            if(debug)
            {
                alert('Error in Services detection via Sector__c')
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //Signer 1 = Business Integrity Director Role
        CRL = getUserInfoForRole('Business Integrity Director', 'Business Integrity', '1');
        CCTM = 'Business Integrity~Signer;';
        CCRM = 'Business Integrity~Business Integrity;';

        //Signer 2 = Practice Lead with Signing Power
        CRL = CRL + getUserInfoForRole('{!Contract.Sector__c} Lead', 'Practice Lead', '2');
        CCTM = CCTM + 'Practice Lead~Signer;';
        CCRM = CCRM + 'Practice Lead~Practice Lead;';


        if(debug)
        {
            alert('DocuSign NOT Checked')
        }

        if(prod)
        {
            DST = '855790D3-6121-496F-B870-D0B276A54611'
        }
        else
        {
            DST = 'A906436D-5352-40DE-A9F8-1EE0795E4266'
        }

        if(debug)
        {
            alert(DST)
        }       

    }




    //Need Error Check, No OppId, 

    location = "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Contract.id}&DST="+DST+"&CRL="+CRL+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CCRM="+CCRM;


}
catch (e)
{

    alert("Error Occured"+e.message);

}
finally
{
    if(debug)
    {
        alert(location);
    }
    else
    {
        window.location.href = location;
    }
}
```