# DocuSign for Salesforce - Add Recipients in Envelope through URL

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, docusignapi

I am currently working on a Salesforce DocuSign project where I created a button
to send emails with attachments from the Account Object. The button calls the DocuSign Salesforce app with the link

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();
```

Is there a way for me to pass the Contact Id that is linked to the Account record to the DocuSign Envelope to be the Recipient?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as passing the Contact record ID.

I honestly have never done this before, but this post below gives the concept of what you would need to do:

[DocuSign for Salesforce Custom Button - Auto Populate Recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262643/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-auto-populate-recipients/26515534#26515534)

In summary, you will need to build your own DocuSign custom button logic:

https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-logic.pdf

Read up on how to use the **CRL** parameter.

Then embed a SOQL query to your button logic to pull Contacts related to your Account record.

I hope this pushes you in the right direction.